# Having trouble with programmatically created constraint

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am building an app for iPhone and iPad using swift 5 and I have having some issues with constraints.

First I created all the views, stack views and labels I will need.

```
let st  = UIStackView()
let st1 = UIStackView()
let st2 = UIStackView()

let underConstructionStackView = UIStackView()
let scheduleJobsStackView = UIStackView()
let withoutScheduleStackView = UIStackView()
let withoutPMStackView = UIStackView()

var underConstruction = PieChartView()
var scheduleJobs = PieChartView()
var withoutSchedule = PieChartView()
var withoutPM = PieChartView()

var underConstructionLabel = UILabel()
var scheduleJobsLabel = UILabel()
var withoutScheduleLabel = UILabel()
var withoutPMLabel = UILabel()
```

Then I set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false for all of these items:

```
st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

underConstruction.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scheduleJobs.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
withoutSchedule.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
withoutPM.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

underConstructionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scheduleJobsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
withoutScheduleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
withoutPMLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Then I set the stack views directions and add it to the view

```
let size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

if size.width < size.height {
    st.axis = .horizontal
    st1.axis = .vertical
    st2.axis = .vertical
} else {
    st.axis = .horizontal
    st1.axis = .horizontal
    st2.axis = .horizontal
}

underConstructionStackView.axis = .vertical
scheduleJobsStackView.axis = .vertical
withoutScheduleStackView.axis = .vertical
withoutPMStackView.axis = .vertical

st.distribution = .fill
st.alignment = .center

view.addSubview(st)

st.addArrangedSubview(st1)
st.addArrangedSubview(st2)

underConstructionStackView.addArrangedSubview(underConstructionLabel)
underConstructionStackView.addArrangedSubview(underConstruction)
st1.addArrangedSubview(underConstructionStackView)

scheduleJobsStackView.addArrangedSubview(scheduleJobsLabel)
scheduleJobsStackView.addArrangedSubview(scheduleJobs)
st1.addArrangedSubview(scheduleJobsStackView)

withoutScheduleStackView.addArrangedSubview(withoutScheduleLabel)
withoutScheduleStackView.addArrangedSubview(withoutSchedule)
st2.addArrangedSubview(withoutScheduleStackView)

withoutPMStackView.addArrangedSubview(withoutPMLabel)
withoutPMStackView.addArrangedSubview(withoutPM)
st2.addArrangedSubview(withoutPMStackView)

st1.distribution = .fillEqually
st2.distribution = .fillEqually
```

Then I programmatically created the constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    st.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
    st.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
    st.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.communityButton.topAnchor,constant:60),

    underConstruction.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: underConstruction.heightAnchor),

    scheduleJobs.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scheduleJobs.heightAnchor),

    withoutSchedule.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: withoutSchedule.heightAnchor),

    withoutPM.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: withoutPM.heightAnchor),
])
```

My issues is the PieChartView(),

- iPhone - Landscape - PieChartView need to be smaller
- iPhone - Portrait - PieChartView could be smaller
- iPad - Portrait - PieChartView are way too big

This looks fine on iPad - Landscape

(Screen shots attached)

What do I need to do to my constraint to get the PieChartView to fit in between self.communityButton and the grid I have below the PieChartView?

I have tried setting a bottom constraint on the UIStackView to the top of the grid topAnchor, but the grid is a Shinobigrid and does not have a topAnchor.....what should I do?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I have tried the following

```
if size.width < size.height
        {

            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad  {

                widthCon = st.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1)

            }
            else
            {
                widthCon = st.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.95)
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad  {

                widthCon = st.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)

            }
            else
            {
                widthCon = st.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)
            }

        }

        widthCon.isActive = true
```

on initial load everything looks great.....however when I rotate the device everything is messed up.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad  {

            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait  {

                widthCon = st.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)
            }
            else {

                widthCon = st.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1)

            }
        }
        else {

            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {

                widthCon = st.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.50)

            }
            else{

                widthCon = st.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)

            }
        }

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
st.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor), 
st.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
```

as it fills the screen in all devices  , You need to substitute with

```
var widthCon:NSLayoutConstraint!

 //put inside activate
 st.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor)

// outside activate
widthCon =  st.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8)
widthCon.isActive = true
```

Then according to the combination you need to check do

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad  {

        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait  {
            //
           widthCon.constant = size.width * 0.5 // lower it
        }
        else {
            //
        }
    }
    else {

        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
            // 
        }
        else{
            //
        }
    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Comment: This works on initial load, but when I rotate the device it to landscape everything looks too small, when I rotate it to Portrait everything looks too big.....What I did on the inital load is had the conditions for .pad or not and inside those conditions had a condition of landscape or Portrait...ill update my question.

Comment: you create a new constraint , follow what in answer for example for 0.7 ratio do `widthCon.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.7`

Comment: I've tried that too, did not work....instead of UIScreen.main.bounds I am going to try with the size parameter.

Comment: using the size parameter instead of UIScreen.main.bounds works!